# Performance issue with strpos and foreach

Tags: php, performance, foreach, strpos

I have the following array declared:

```
$array = array(
   "Car" => array("(car;", "(is Car;", "(suv;"),
   "Boat" => array("(boat;", "(Boat;"),
   "Motorcycle" => array("(cycle;")
 );
```

Then I query a MySQL DB for around 20,000 results as strings (`$string`), so what I want to do is search for the subarray values (i.e. **"(car;"**) in one of the strings similar to this one **"the awesome (car; offroad;)"**

To achieve this I tried the following:

```
foreach($string as $element) {
    foreach($array as $key=>type) {
            foreach($type as $search_string) {
                if(strpos($element, $search_string) !== FALSE) { //if the search term is present 
                    return $key;
                    break 2; //exit the loop as it found the right device type
                }
            } //second foreach strings to search for
        } return 'Other';
    }
```

The Problem is it works if i query very little results, but for thousand of lines it just consumes a lot of memory and it takes a very long time to return the result.

How can I improve the performance of the code?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to store the whole result of your query? Perhaps you could do your search while fetching the query result and keep only the rows you need.

Comment: You're in the middle of [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - either use fulltext search, or (yes, yes, it's not good in MySQL) special solutions, like Sphinx.

Comment: RDBMS's are not just dumb data stores, they are designed for querying. Dumping all the data into memory and then querying it with php is not the answer